Transpose XLSX and send to database, using Pandas
I have a xlsx file that is structured in an unorthodox way. Simplified, it looks like this:




A
B
C
D
E
F




1








2

member_id
101
102
102
103


3

first_name
paul
john
george
ringo


4

last_name
mccartney
lennon
harrison
starr



Note the member_id is NOT unique (it makes sense in the original data).
My goal is to have a table that looks like this:



member_id
first_name
last_name




101
paul
mccartney


102
john
lennon


102
george
harrison


103
ringo
starr



(note that member_id is still not unique)
So my approach is to read this table into Python, transpose it, and write it to a database.
This is what I have so far:
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name='data', engine='openpyxl', skiprows=[0])

This is already off to a bad start, as it seems that Pandas wants my columns to be unique (note that the columns are called "102" and "102.1"):
   Unnamed: 0  member_id        101     102     102.1    104

0         NaN  first_name       paul    john    george  ringo

1         NaN  last_name   mccartney  lennon  harrison  starr

If I got the issue with the member_id fixed, I would drop the empty column:
df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis='columns')

Which would give me
    member_id        101     102     102.1    104

0   first_name       paul    john    george  ringo

1   last_name   mccartney  lennon  harrison  starr

Then I would transpose the table like this:
df = df.transpose()

                     0          1
member_id   first_name  last_name
101               paul  mccartney
102               john     lennon
102.1           george   harrison
104              ringo      starr

Which has an odd first row of what used to be the index, which I can't seem to drop.
Help is greatly appreciated!

There's probably a more elegant solution but this does the trick:
df = pd.read_excel("my_table.xlsx", skiprows=1, header=None)
df = df.drop(columns=0, axis="columns")
df = df.transpose()
todict = df.to_dict(orient="list")
todict = { v[0]: v[1:] for v in todict.values() }
for k,v in todict.items(): # you can obviously skip this
    print(f"{k}: {v}")
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(todict)


First change the column name, then delete the first row.
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
#df.drop(index=df.index[0], inplace=True)


Thanks for your reply, but this is not very feasible, as I work with 90+ columns, some of which have unknown names.

What I ended up doing is this I imported the headers and the data separately, and combined the two afterwards:
First read the header row:
col_headers = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet,  header=None, nrows=1, skiprows=[0]).values[0]

Then I get the data, skipping the header row:
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name=sheet, header=None, skiprows=[0, 1])

Then I combine the two, like so:
df.columns = col_headers

Then I drop the empty columns:
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') 

Then I make the first column (that has all the headers of what will be the columns after the transposition) the index:
df = df.set_index('member_id')

And finally, I can transpose:
df = df.transpose()

